# Pointer to pointer in a structure

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

How can a structure's member (which is a pointer) be accessed through another pointer? Let's say that *ptr is the pointer i want to use to access *time, which is the pointer that belongs to the structure. Is it correct if I write ptr->time?

Would it be correct if I wrote ptr->time = v[i], if I wanted to assign the values of v[i] (array) to *time?

Comment: Please post a clear use case that you have in mind. Don't describe some abstract code.

Comment: You can have a pointer to any address in your process memory space. So you can point to anything you want.

Comment: @Fredrik: That is not exactly correct. It is over-simplified.

Comment: 'Would it be correct if I wrote ptr->time = v[i], if I wanted to assign the values of v[i] (array) to *time?' well if the two types are assignable it looks OK to me.  Why not try it:)

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be correct if I wrote ptr->time = v[i], if I wanted to assign the values of v[i] (array) to *time?

No. If you have...

```
struct {
    int *time;
} *ptr;
int v[10], i = 0;
```

...then you have to write *(ptr->time) = v[i]

If time is a pointer, being inside a struct change nothing to that. So if you want to access the int pointed by time, you have to deference it too.